# ASP.NET Identity cookie and subdomains

Tags: authentication, cookies, subdomain, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to share my ASP.NET Identity cookie across subdomains. Currently just locally.

- sub1.domain.local
- sub2.domain.local

I have the **same machine key** on both sites, but a cookie created on sub1 does not validate on sub2 and vice versa. The resulting cookie domain is always ".domain.local" (which should be correct??)

This is my setup in Startup class:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
            CookieDomain = ".domain.local",
        });
```

I've tried on just localhost:siteport for each site, but same result (cookie domain blank, resolving to "localhost")

I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe someone can point me in the right direction? Thanks

**UPDATE**

Okay, so I've figured out that the cookie is in fact shared between the subdomains, but it's only considered valid on the subdomain that created the cookie. Need to find a way to know why the authentication fails on the other site..

Comment: Did you find a valid solution for this? 
I've tried everything. I've set the cookie-options, I've set the MachineKey, I've set the Startup attributes and I've updated the NuGet packages. 
Nothing seems to be working for me. 
My subdomain can see the cookie for the domain - but it won't authenticate using it :(

I'm growing a bit desperate :)

Comment: I don't remember at this point whether it made any difference, but I also set the CookieName property. I currently have it working on 2 sites locally and 2 sites remotely on dev.sub.mydomain.com and sub.mydomain.com respectively. Cookiedomain being .mydomain.com. I use SSL for both environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of headscratching I noticed i difference in version numbers in various Identity packages. I updated the various packages from Nuget, and wouldn't you know. It worked!

What worries me is that it only updated from minor versions (e.g. Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies from 3.0.0.0 to 3.0.1.0). I don't hope they have to stay aligned like that in the future..

Comment: BTW, you can set `Specific Version` to `false` in Reference Properties. To ignore versions number. But you should use this only in cases where both versions don't have compatibility issues. Like in your case

Answer (score 0):

You need to set Cookie Path to `./` global root folder. This way cookie will be available to all sites under root directory.