# MVC and WebAPI single signon

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, single-sign-on, asp.net-web-api2

I'm currenty working on a project that consist of 2 parts:

**www.domain.com**
This is a MVC 5 website using authentication through Owin.Security

**api.domain.com**

This is a WebAPI project containing an API for internal use only.

What I need to do is to setup single signon between the two sites so that when a user signs in on the MVC site then he will be able to make authenticated requests against the WebAPI's methods marked with [Authorize].

I've set up both product with the same MachineKey:

And on the MVC site I register the following on startup:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
                CookieDomain = ".domain.com"
            });
```

Yet it doesn't work. I can authenticate the user fine on the website - but when I make a request to the API I get an 401 (not authorized).

Can any of you guys help me out with what I'm missing?

I've had a look at this article: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc(v=vs.100).aspx

but since I'm not using Forms Authentication I'm not sure what good it will do me :(

I think I'm just missing a small essential piece - but I can't quite find it at the moment :)

I now I can easily fix this by merging my web an API projects (so that I have my API controllers in the MVC site) - but I would really like to avoid this and have them running on different subdomains.

Thank you.

Comment: IMO. www.domain.com is the main domain and api.domain.com is a subdomain, so the CookieDomain, will only work on where it is accounted for.

an API project with in MVC 5  or earlier to MVC 3 should work as this route. www.domain.com/api/{ControllerName}

If you use the add WebAPI in your project. It will actually create it for your and scaffold it. If I am correct, you build an Web API Seperated from the Solution project and trying to connect them together?

Comment: True - but I would really prefer NOT to have the WebAPI controllers, models, DTO's etc. as part of my web solution - if at all possible.

Comment: I've tried the following approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29318201/asp-net-identity-cookie-and-subdomains
But I still can't get it to work. 
The cookie exists just fine on the subdomain - but it isn't being used for authentication :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I FINALLY found the answer - and as with all great answers, it's a simple one. 
Everything in my setup worked like a charm - but in the WebApiConfig.cs file there is a pesky little line:

```
config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
```

Which tells WebAPI to only use bearer token authentication. 
Removing this line solved all of my problems and made my day :)